# How to build a dynamic nested grid layout in mvvm pattern?

Tags: c#, mvvm, layout, dynamic, grid

How can i create a dynamic grid layout using mvvm pattern?

My current model is something like (obviously it include the implementation of `INotifyPropertyChanged`):

```
public class Container{
    ObservableCollection<Row> Rows;
}

public class Row{
    ObservableCollection<Column> Columns;
    int Height;       //in percentage
}

public class Column{
    int Width;        //in percentage
}
```

and in mvvm i have

```
ObservableCollection<Container> Containers;
```

I would show an object Container in a grid, proportional to the dimension (height and width) and filling the whole parent control (a tab for each container's element). Until now, using nested `ItemControl` i am able to show the corrent number of rows and columns, but i can't make them of the actual dimension and they don't fill the parent control.

Comment: I did write a intro into MVVM. Look at the parts about Templates, particular the ones targetting a ViewModel class. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/b1a8bf14-4acd-4d77-9df8-bdb95b02dbe2/lets-talk-about-mvvm?forum=wpf

Comment: This data structure implies that each row can have a different number of columns, and that the columns in each row can be a different width - is this really what you want?

Comment: @Peregrine yes, exactly! i know this is not easy, but i need it for build a sort of interface designer. From this wpf app users can define their custum layout to show some data. Thanks.

Comment: I tried nested itemscontrol, datagrid, grid and many other. The problem is always that rows and columns don't fill all parent control, but they remain small.